# How to send and receive raw string from MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, server

I am working on a SQL Developer-like application, in which user enters some SQL command and the result from the server is shown in a `<div>` on web page.

The problem is that user can enter ANY string, valid SQL or not, for example if an user sends `select * from employees;` I want to receive and display in 
the `<div>` text EXACTLY as below :

```
+---------+----------+---------------+----------+
| user_id | username | full_name     | password |
+---------+----------+---------------+----------+
|       1 | john     | John Doe      | admin    |
```

And when he enters a bad SQL string, the `<div>` message should be the standard MySQL error strings , for example :

```
mysql> select * from usrsss;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydb.usrsss' doesn't exist
```

I know about security risk , I do not care about it at this point.

Can this be done, as I have no control on the SQL string syntax being sent by user?

Comment: Why couldn'it? You're besically asking us if you can execute SQL queries on a SQL database. Yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the prompt you see there `mysql>` represents the **MySQL Shell**. This is not SQL or JDBC but a command line interface provided by MySQL.

This MySQL Shell allows you to execute:

- SQL statements.
- A variety of other statements that are NOT part of SQL.

The JDBC API you want to use will allow you to run the first group of statements -- the SQL statements. Unfortunately, it won't allow you to run the second one, so you are out of luck for this one.

Also, for the first group the JDBC API will provide error codes and error messages that are not exactly the same ones you see when using the MySQL Shell.

Bottom line, you can simulate some of these commands, but it will not be the exact same experience that you probably expect.

However... and this is a big one, why do you want to do this in the first place? One of my developers asked me if he could do this, since it's not difficult to implement; this way we could easily run any SQL command from the web page. Great? Well... no. This is a **HUGE SECURITY RISK**. If anyone hacks your web page, you would be exposing the whole database.

In other words, **don't deploy this code to production.**

Comment: The OP said they didn't care about the security risk. So you should explain instead that it's not just security that's at risk. The whole database itself is at stake!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `java.sql.Connection`,

- create a statement first by using `.createStatement()`.
- use `.executeQuery()` for searching
- and `.executeUpdate()` for inserts, updates and deletes

When searching identify the number of columns to create a table.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(String sql);
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
```

In `ResultSetMetaData`,

- `.getColumnCount()` will give you the column count.
- in a for loop create the columns, while creating `.getColumnName(int index)` will give you the column name.

After creating the table, iterate the `ResultSet`,

```
while (rs.next()) {
    rs.getString(int columnIndex);
}
```

use the above method to get values, and add rows to your table.

Don't forget to surround the code block with

```
try{

} catch(Exception e){
     e.getMessage();
}
```

so if anything goes wrong you can get the `SQLException` thrown. That will include a message, the probable cause for the error.

Work your way out... Enjoy!

Comment: It would be far simpler to use `execute(..)` because that can be used for all types of statements (even those that produce multiple results and update counts).